# How do I load a local HTML into CefSharp that contains a CSS-stylesheet?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

**OS:** Windows 7
**Cef Version:** Wpf

Hello all,
I'm trying to load a local HTML file (https://pastebin.com/wgnTKcpS) that uses the MathQuill formula editor (http://mathquill.com). However, when using this code:

```
MathQuillBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (MathQuillBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized)
        MathQuillBrowser.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/mathquill.html"), "https://somefakeurl-mathquill.com");
};
```

to load the HTML file into the `ChromiumBrowser`, the MathQuill span doesn't show up in the `ChromiumBrowser`at the Wpf window. What am I doing wrong?

**How to reproduce the problem:**

- Create a new Wpf Application in VS and install CefSharp with Nuget
- Go to the bin\x86\Debug file of the project and put the HTML mentioned above (in a file named mathquill.html) and the latest version of MathQuill.
- Create a `ChromiumBrowser` control and add it to the main control of some window.
- Load the Html into `ChromiumBrowser` with the code mentioned above.

**Important note:** The C# code above works (html elements show up) with elements that don't load external CSS stylesheets. Also, the html code works as expected if you open it in a browser like Chrome.

Comment: I think you need to remember that CEF is a web *browser*, not a web *server*. The browser doesn't know where that CSS file is (you manually loaded the HTML as text remember) and so it can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cef browser doesn't know where the CSS file is, so it can't find it. The easy solution is to use a CDN (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mathquill, for MathQuill).